# grunt - browse subdirectories and create a js/css file for each

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a folder named modules. Inside are small angular apps each with their own .js/.css files.

```
GruntFile.js
module
  -> admin
     -> js
     -> css
     -> index.html
  -> stuff1
     -> ...
  -> stuff2
     -> ...
```

I am trying to find a script, that would scan each of the modules and create a .js file inside each, without the need to make GruntFile.js in each of them.

Also I don't want to put all the /module/admin/js/... and /module/stuff1/js/... in the grunt concat command as there are a lot of modules and a lot of js files.

So far i am here:

```
grunt.registerTask("concat-modules", function(){
    grunt.file.expand('client/modules/*').forEach(function(dir){
        console.log(dir);

    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I think i have the soulution:

```
    grunt.registerTask("concat-modules", function(){
    grunt.file.expand('client/modules/*').forEach(function(dir){
        //console.log(dir);
        var module_name = dir.substring(dir.lastIndexOf("/")+1, dir.length);
        //console.log(module_name);
        var concat = grunt.config.get('concat') || {};
        concat[dir] = {
            src:[
                dir + '/js/*.js', 
                dir + '/js/controllers/*.js',
                dir + '/js/directives/*.js',
                dir + '/js/helpers/*.js',
                dir + '/js/services/*.js',
            ],
            dest: dir + '/js/combo.js'
        }

        grunt.config.set('concat', concat);

    });
    grunt.task.run('concat');

});
```

Comment: You can say: src: [dir + '/js/**/*.js', '!' + dir + '/js/combo.js']

Comment: Thx :), now i have to figure out how to set and run concat without running the whole concat, thats inside initConfig